# C# Forms application picturebox drawing

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have two picture boxes on a form, each is being updated by an event delegated from other threads.

When I am only updating one of the pictureboxes, it is being repainted with a high frequency (54-60Hz). When I update both pictureboxes, as is expected, the refresh rate of slows, but the OnPaint method of the different picture is being called at very different rates (6Hz vs 45-47Hz).

This is how the events are raised..

```
class WorkingThread {

    protected event EventHandler<OutputImageUpdateArgs> NewImageAvailable;
    protected void OnNewImageAvailable(OutputImageUpdateArgs e ) 
    {
         NewImageAvailable.Invoke(this, e );
    }

    ...
    SomeFunction(){
        ...
        OnNewImageAvailable( tmp );
    }
}
```

This is in the UI class/thread

```
class UI{
    SomeInitialisationFunction(){
        ...
        pass in the new event handle to the worker threads..
        .. new EventHandler<OutputImageUpdateArgs>( OnNewImageAvailable )
        new EventHandler<OutputImageUpdateArgs>( OnSecondImageAvailable)...
    }

    void OnNewImageAvailable(object sender, OutputImageUpdateArgs e ) {            
        BeginInvoke((Action)(()=> {pictureBox1.Image = e.NewImage;}
        ));
    }

    void OnSecondImageAvailable ( object sender, OutputImageUpdateArgs e ) {            
        BeginInvoke( (Action)(() => {pictureBox2.Image = e.NewImage;}
        ) );
    }
}
```

I would like to know two things:

1. Why are the refresh rates for the two picture boxes so different?
2. Can I control when a picturebox is redrawn so that I only redraw both pictures at fixed intervals? I would like to think that I should be able to paint each a 25Hz, given that I can paint the sum of the two at approximately 50Hz currently.